# Login page cannot authenticate my password

Tags: php, authentication

I having a hard time authenticating my login credentials on the login page that I have created. It seems that it cant recognize the password I have created for my accounts. It acknowledges that an account exists but it doesn't seem to match up the password entered and the hash_password stored.

```
<?php

 include('config.php');
 session_start();

 if (isset($_POST['Login'])) {

     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $user_password = $_POST['user_password'];

     $query = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM user_info WHERE USERNAME=:username");
     $query->bindParam("username", $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $query->execute();

     $result = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

     if (!$result) {
         echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong!</p>';
     } 
     else {
        echo 'here';
        echo $user_password;
        echo $result['user_password'];

         if (password_verify($user_password, $result['user_password'])) {
             $_SESSION['user_id'] = $result['ID'];
             echo '<p class="success">Congratulations, you are logged in!</p>';
         } else {
             echo '<p class="error">Username password combination is wrong! 2</p>';
         }
     }
 }

 ?>
```

Comment: Can you provide with a sample code how you've stored your password? Also when Debugging log the output of has password and then log the output of $result['user_password'] to see if they do match. Also log $user_password to see if it is even being sent. Provide the input for the passwords and their hash /output.

Comment: Maybe you're entering the wrong password?

Comment: @stefantigro They won't match, because `password_hash()` uses a different salt each time.

Comment: This question is unanswerable while the output of the debug `echo`s are amiss.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was that I  had to adjust the length of the password variable. It was originally 20 and obviously when you hash a password the length is significantly longer. Therefore I simply changed the password length to 255.

Answer (score -1):

`password_verify` needs hash. Maybe your second parameter of this function is plain password or something like that. That's above works fine:

```
$hash = password_hash('test1234', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
print_r(password_verify('test1234', $hash));
```

Comment: Ok, but there is no informations, about method of creating that hash. So if it doesn't match, it's look like there is no problem with function but implementation.